# Add second legend to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have this data

LUI

```
structure(list(year = c("2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
"2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018"), month = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), Avdischarge = c(928, 466.8, 
347, 257.2, 129.8, 146.9, 58.3, 48.47, 49.35, 44.27, 55.2, 298.3
), IndustrialCompound = c(0.25, 0.25, 0.4, 0, 0.3125, 0.166666666666667, 
0.142857142857143, 0.125, 0.25, 0.0909090909090909, 0.333333333333333, 
0.166666666666667), Pharmaceutical = c(0.75, 0.75, 0.5, 0.833333333333333, 
0.5, 0.833333333333333, 0.714285714285714, 0.75, 0.5, 0.818181818181818, 
0.5, 0.833333333333333), Pesticide = c(0, 0, 0.1, 0.166666666666667, 
0.1875, 0, 0.142857142857143, 0.125, 0.25, 0.0909090909090909, 
0.166666666666667, 0), TotalOvershootings = c(0.181818181818182, 
0.166666666666667, 0.344827586206897, 0.285714285714286, 0.4, 
0.272727272727273, 0.318181818181818, 0.347826086956522, 0.4, 
0.366666666666667, 0.4, 0.3)), row.names = 37:48, class = "data.frame")
```

I plotted some scatterpies along the discharge like this:

```
pieperlui<- ggplot(LUI, aes(x=month)) +
  geom_line(aes(y= as.factor(round(Avdischarge,1)), group=1), 
            color="navy", 
            size=1.5, 
            alpha=0.8) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks= LUI$month)+
  geom_scatterpie(aes(x=month, y=2, group=type, r = TotalOvershootings*1.5), 
                  cols= c("IndustrialCompound", "Pharmaceutical", "Pesticide"),
                  alpha= 0.7,
                  color=NA,
                  data= LUI)+
  labs(y="Average discharge (m3/s)", x= "Month", 
       title= "Discharge and Compounds percentage of exceedance per month (2018)",
       subtitle = "Luik")+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=13),
        axis.text.x  = element_text(size=13),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=13),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 13),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 15))
```

And got this

[image: example]

How can I add the legend of the discharge (line)? And how can I change the size of the subtitle?

Thank you

Comment: Legends are only created for attributes that are in the `aes()` command. Try moving `color` into the `aes()` portion of your `geom_line`.

Comment: As a separate point, you might want to consider making `Avdischarge` a numeric value because at the moment the y-axis scale is super misleading!

Comment: @JakeFeuerman will try that.